# Javascript random table td -- nooverlap vertical-horizontal

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, html-table, overlay

I'm trying to avoid horizontal and vertical lines.
It stopped working with the Javascript array and for the rest of it.
I don't know how to create Javascript to randomly generate the first line and don't overlap with daeumjul. Please let me know. The code has been raised to jsfiddle.

**Screenshot:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9SwK.png]

---

**Javascript**

```
var arr_person = ["#B22222","#0000cd","#FF00FF","#DAA520","#008000","#FF69B4","#4B0082","#E6E6FA","#ADD8E6","#90EE90"];
    var arr_date = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu','fri'];
    var arr_subject = ['subject1','subject2','subject3','subject4','subject5'];
    var arr_subject_check = new Array();
    for(m=0; m < arr_subject.length; m++){
        arr_subject_check[m] = new Array();
    }
    var arr_time = ['morning','after'];
    var str = "";

    function pickFromPool() {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr_pool.length);
        return arr_pool.splice(r,1)[0];

    }

    str += "<table>";

    for(var i=0; i < arr_date.length; i++){ // arr_date
        var arr_pool = arr_person.slice();
        str += "<tr>";
        for(var j=0; j < arr_subject.length; j++ ){ //arr_subject

            var arr_subject_check_cur = arr_subject_check[j].slice();
            for(var n=0; n < arr_subject_check_cur.length; n++) {
                var dup_index = arr_pool.indexOf(arr_subject_check_cur[n]);
                if(dup_index < 0) {

                } else {
                    arr_pool.splice(dup_index,1);

                }
            }
            for(var k=0; k < arr_time.length; k++ ){
                var pickedValue = pickFromPool();

                arr_subject_check[j].push(pickedValue);
                if(k == 0){
                    str += "<td style='border-left:#fff 4px solid;background-color:" + pickedValue + "'></td>";
                } else {
                    str += "<td style='background-color:" + pickedValue + "'></td>";
                }

            }

            for(var m=0; m < arr_subject_check_cur.length; m++) {
                if(arr_subject_check_cur[m] !== '') {
                    arr_pool.push(arr_subject_check_cur[m]);
                }
            }
        }
        str += "</tr>";
    }


    str += "</table>";

    jQuery('body').html(str);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ipadorusa/vx8t25ts/1/

I'm trying to avoid horizontal and vertical lines.